# What's the part number of this LEGO element?

Tags: part-identification

[image]

Can anybody help me identify this part?

Comment: Following the instructions https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/154/how-do-i-identify-a-lego-part and without any info (is it new? old?) nor having it in hand (turn around and read number): Go to e.g. Rebrickable, there do search with restrictions: 1/ has appeared in white, 2/ exclude printed parts. Now you get too many results ("1000" = maxed out); so split time in sets that give less than 1000 results (1945--1995, 1995--2001, 2001--2005, ... some 8/9 setc), then leaf through the 9--10pages each gives... So by chance, it appears on page 8 (of 9) for the 1945--1995 search... pff.

Comment: OK the above can be sharper (no need to overlap years, so 1945--1995, 1996--...), and faster using the Categories (I'd guess: "Panels", "Angled plates", ... the correct choice "Transportation" I wouldn't have guessed but it contains so any that I'd included it)...  Maybe Brickowl is easier; you'd want multi-category-select for one search.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's a rather old part (50 years, actually) used mainly for tipper buckets in trains or trucks, you can see it in [this train](https://brickset.com/sets/120-1/Complete-Freight-Train-Set-with-Tipper-Trucks) for example:

[image]

Its part ID is [3145](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3145&in=S).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm really interested to know how you did to find that. That's impressive! I'm not a Lego expert at all, but reading the comments of user3445853 it seemed really difficult.

Comment: Well, my first LEGO train, [171](https://brickset.com/sets/171-1/Train-Set-without-Motor) had two in red, so with that info it was rather straightforward. Aside from that, there's a question on the subject with a [very good answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/157/99) but let's face it, sometimes it's just a matter of remembering the part at all.