# What are these LEGO pieces? Dark grey, notched, a hole out to the side

Tags: part-identification

[image: Unknown LEGO piece]
Could you please help me identify this LEGO piece?

Comment: Welcome Marcin! Please post a larger picture - this picture is too small to make out any identifying details. Thanks!

Comment: Aside from the picture being very small, are there any other details you can give about this piece? The exact dimensions, how long have you had this piece. any identifying marks like a LEGO logo or part ID etc.

Comment: [The canonical](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405/problems-with-set-identification-questions/409#409) is *[How do I identify a LEGO part?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/154/)*.

Answer (score 16):

I think I found it, it's actually two pieces on top of each other - 99563 on top of 36840 (sorry I do not have a better picture, it is cropped from a photo I found online):

[image: 99563]

[99563](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99563&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Ingot%20/%20Bar&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=C&C=85)

[image: 36840]

[36840](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=36840&name=Bracket%201%20x%201%20-%201%20x%201%20Inverted&category=%5BBracket%5D#T=C&C=85)

Comment: Nice work! That looks right to me.