# Parts with no part number how is it identified? (need help, but for future too)

Tags: part-identification

So, the white piece has identification, but the front cover does not.  How are these identified? It's from an old space set from the 90's. I have tons of non typical parts that seem to have no identification.  It **does** have some numbers on it - 1-02 what is that referencing? I know this was from a few sets, probably

[image: Part]

Comment: Answers to [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/154/13390) might help you

Answer (score 8):

The box is part [4345](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4345) (or a variant). On BrickLink, that gives **This Door, Frame fits with the following Door:**. And those parts are [4346](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4346). But you want one with a pattern on it, so the BrickLink search you need is [4346p*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=4346p*). There's only 60 of them, and one looks right: [4346pb05 Container, Box 2 x 2 x 2 Door with Slot with Red and Yellow Controls Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4346pb05)

[image: 4346pb05]

As for "1-02 what is that referencing" it is almost definitely a way for Lego to track which part of which mold made that part, so that if any are reported as mis-formed, they can track it down more easily.

Comment: Wow, I never knew you could search with a * match. That's going to be useful in the future!

Comment: The first time you see it, the potential is mind-blowing.

Comment: Thanks! I didn’t realize every part wasn’t identified!

Comment: @SQLALLSTAR the round 1x1 brick <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3062b> has been in use since 1976 in this form, but only in the past few years has it had any marking on it saying Lego, let alone a part number.

Answer (score 7):

These parts are [Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Red and Yellow Controls and Two White Stripes on Left Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bp68&C=1),

[image: 3069bp68]

Note the similarity to [this part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bpb0785&C=1) (below). You can see the left side is different.

[image: 3069bpb0785]

[Container, Box 2 x 2 x 2 Door with Slot with Red and Yellow Controls Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4346pb05&C=11), attached to [Container, Box 2 x 2 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4345&C=1)

[image: 4346pb05]
[image: 4345]

As for finding pieces yourself, I find the [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page) search to be most useful. Obviously as you become more familiar it will be easier. Searching by colour is usually a good way to start.

To find your parts I searched ["white tile 1 x 2 pattern red yellow"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=white%20tile%201%20x%202%20pattern%20red%20yellow) and ["black container door"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=black%20container%20door)

Comment: Unfortunately, some of the pattern descriptions are just things like "Container, Box 2 x 2 x 2 Door with Slot with M:Tron Pattern" which does **not** help. That's why I recommend searching with google instead of BrickLink directly - if you have a way to describe a piece, google will show you where **other** people have used that wording to describe it, while BrickLink can **only** show you its one standard description. Peeron used to have alternate keywords, which helped find things where you didn't already know exactly the right phrase.

Comment: @RSchulz Good point. It's always possible to try both anyway. I probably find Bricklink easy _because_ I have a pretty good understanding of their naming conventions (which is where gaining experience will help). Still, the number one best way is to search by part ID if you can find it (a 4-5 digit number).